# Generic method overloading compilation error in VB

Tags: c#, vb.net, generics

I have a problem with the VB.NET compiler failing to compile a class (in a separate C# assembly) which contains two overloads of a method with generic arguments. The equivalent code in C# compiles against the same assembly with no errors.

Here are the two method signatures:

```
protected void SetValue<T>(T newValue, ref T oldValue)
protected void SetValue<T>(T? newValue, ref T? oldValue) where T : struct
```

Here is the code to three assemblies that demonstrate the problem. The first is the C# assembly with a Base class that implements the generic methods. The second is a C# class derived from Base and calls both overloads of SetValue correctly. The third is a VB class  also derived from Base, but fails to compile with the following error message:

Error   1   Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'SetValue' is most specific for these arguments:
    'Protected Sub SetValue(Of T As Structure)(newValue As System.Nullable(Of Integer), ByRef oldValue As System.Nullable(Of Integer))': Not most specific.
    'Protected Sub SetValue(Of T)(newValue As System.Nullable(Of Integer), ByRef oldValue As System.Nullable(Of Integer))': Not most specific.

1. Base Class assembly

   example:

   ```
   public class Base
   {
       protected void SetValue<T>(T newValue, ref T oldValue)
       {
       }               
       protected void SetValue<T>(T? newValue, ref T? oldValue) where T : struct
       {
       }
   }
   ```
2. C# Derived Class

   example:

   ```
   public class DerivedCSharp : Base
   {
       private int _intValue;
       private int? _intNullableValue;    
       public void Test1(int value)
       {
           SetValue(value, ref _intValue);
       }        
       public void Test2(int? value)
       {
           SetValue(value, ref _intNullableValue);
       }
   }
   ```
3. VB Derived Class

   example:

   ```
   Public Class DerivedVB
       Inherits Base    
       Private _intValue As Integer
       Private _intNullableValue As Nullable(Of Integer)    
       Public Sub Test1(ByVal value As Integer)
           SetValue(value, _intValue)
       End Sub    
       Public Sub Test2(ByVal value As Nullable(Of Integer))
           SetValue(value, _intNullableValue)
       End Sub
   End Class
   ```

Am I doing something wrong in the VB code, or are C# & VB different when it comes to generic overload resolution? If I make the method arguments in Base non-generic then everything compiles correctly, but then I have to implement SetValue for every type that I wish to support.

Comment: What versions of Visual Studio & .Net are you using?

Comment: I have tried it in VS2005 & VS2010 Beta 1 with the same result. I assume VS2008 will be the same.

Comment: This smells like a compiler bug. You should report it.

Comment: Jeff, thanks for restoring my original generic code.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have to help the VB compiler a little to pick the right overload to call. The following compiles for me

```
Public Sub Test1(ByVal value As Integer)
    SetValue(Of Integer)(value, _intValue)
End Sub

Public Sub Test2(ByVal value As Nullable(Of Integer))
    SetValue(Of Integer)(value, _intNullableValue)
End Sub
```

Comment: This gets around the compiler error, but the call to SetValue inside Test2 resolves to the wrong overload. Good try though! I thought the problem was solved when it compiled correctly.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I've now edited my reply so that Test1 calls SetValue(T, ref T) and Test2 calls SetValue(T?, ref T?).

Answer (score 2):

I stand by my comment that this is most likely a bug. However, I can reproduce it using the Mono VB compiler `vbnc`. The (somewhat mangled) error message here is “No non-narrowing (except object)” – which I presume refers to missing implicit conversions and hence to the same overload resolution problem.

The problem seems to be that the overload resolution of the compiler fails because of the `ByRef` arguments, since that requires some special management which is made explicit in the C# call but not in the VB call.